# Java Swing - Save infos of the figures as SVG

Tags: java, swing, svg, save, save-as

```java
try {
            FileInputStream f = new FileInputStream("proj.bin");
            ObjectInputStream o = new ObjectInputStream(f);
            this.FigureList = (ArrayList<Figure>) o.readObject();
            o.close();
        } catch (Exception x) {
        }

this.addWindowListener(
                new WindowAdapter() {
                    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                        try {
                            FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream("proj.bin");
                            ObjectOutputStream o = new ObjectOutputStream(f);
                            o.writeObject(FigureList);
                            o.flush();
                            o.close();
                        } catch (Exception x) {
                        }
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                });
```

I've been using this code to save the infos of my panel(Figure position, color and those kind of things), so whenever I run the code again, there will be things already there. Can save it as SVG and use this svg file in others apps? I've tried to change ".bin" for ".svg" but it seems it's not that easy.

[You can see my whole code here](https://github.com/Sule26/LP-II/tree/main/Projeto)

Comment: There's no inbuilt support, but several 3rd party libraries exist, for example, [The Apache™ Batik Project](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/using/swing.html) and [JFreeSVG](https://github.com/jfree/jfreesvg)

Comment: *Never* write an empty `catch` block.  At the very least, call the caught exception’s `printStackTrace()` method.